# Using Cauchy Integral Formula to solve an integral

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Evaluate $$\int_\Gamma \frac{\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^2} dz$$
>
> Where $\Gamma$ consists of the sides of the rectangle with vertices at $(1,\pm3i)$ and $(4,\pm2i)$

**My attempt:**

The only singularity is $z_0= \pi$ Therefore by Cauchy's Integral formula

$$\int_\Gamma \frac{\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^2} dz=2\pi i.\cos(\pi)=-2\pi i$$

Would this be correct? Is it a problem that $f(\pi)=0?$

Comment: Try finding the residue term by expanding sin(z) about z=$\pi$ and then dividing the series by $(z-\pi)^2$, find the $a_{-1}$ term and see if it equals -1. If so, then the methods agree.

Comment: Thanks, I get that it equals 1, however I could just as well have incorrectly calculated the residue term

Comment: Would you be able to give me a more concrete answer as to whether my method/answer is correct please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^{2}},z=\pi\right) = \lim_{z\to \pi}\frac{\sin(z)}{z-\pi} \stackrel{DH}{=} \lim_{z\to \pi}\cos(z) = \color{red}{-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you! This means that it doesn't matter if $f(x)$ is 0 at the singularity point. Am I correct?

Comment: @THISISIT453: what is your $f(x)$? $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^2}$ does not equal zero at $z=\pi$, it has a simple pole there. The point is that $\frac{\sin z}{z-\pi}$ is a regular function in a neighbourhood of $z=\pi$.

Comment: Sorry to clarify my $f(z)= \sin(z)$

Comment: @THISISIT453: well, if $f(\pi)\neq 0$, $\frac{f(z)}{(z-\pi)^2}$ has a *double* pole at $z=\pi$, but the residue is still $f'(\pi)$, so $f(\pi)=0$ does not matter that much.